No space left on device when building Docker image
I am trying to build a Docker image, but got an error like:
make: *** [slave.mk:1119: target/docker-lldp.gz] Error 1
mkdir: cannot create directory './target/versions/build/log-20240530215300': No space left on device
chmod: cannot access './target/versions/build/log-20240530215300': No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/collect_version_files: line 18: ./target/versions/build/log-20240530215300/versions-deb-bullseye-amd64: No such file or directory
/usr/sbin/collect_version_files: line 20: ./target/versions/build/log-20240530215300/versions-py3-bullseye-amd64: No such file or directory
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
cp: error writing './target/versions/build/log-20240530215300': No space left on device

df -h shows:
tom@debian:~/sonic-buildimage$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           995M 1000K  994M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        98G   57G   37G  61% /
tmpfs           4.9G     0  4.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           995M   52K  995M   1% /run/user/1000

I don't see any space issue here.
tom@debian:~/sonic-buildimage$ df -i
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev           1264961     407 1264554    1% /dev
tmpfs          1272934     693 1272241    1% /run
/dev/sda1      6561792 1851432 4710360   29% /
tmpfs          1272934       1 1272933    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs          1272934       4 1272930    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           254586      70  254516    1% /run/user/1000

The ./target/versions/build/ is under /home/tom/sonic_image/.
So why does it give "no space" message?

Wild guess: Are you creating many small files? Check with df -i you didn't reach the inode limit.

I am not sure, will many small files cause this problem?

Since I use the virtual box to run the Linux, I just expand the size of memory and increase the processor, the issue has gone.

I don't understand that. Are you building a Docker image inside a Virtualbox VM?
